# Best Way to Lengthen the Romex 10 wire from the Wall to the Stove

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, appliances

I'm hooking up a ceramic stove and the last installer ran Romex 10 w/o armor from the drywall thru cabinets to a J box under the stove. From the J box he used BX to the stove. It worked that way for 20 years.

If the Romex could make it to the J box I would be tempted to do it that way again if it was up to code (I've read various opinions on this but most agree that it is either ok or not dangerous). The problem is that the Romex 10 is too short and will need to be spliced to a longer Romex 10 to make it to the new stove.

What is the best way to accomplish this? If the unarmored Romex is not up to code, my plan is to install a metal J box on the outside of the drywall just below the countertop (there's a 6 inch covered space between the drywall and the first cabinet that will allow the Romex to be hidden). From the J box, I'll run the Romex thru the BX cable thru the cabinets and up to another J box in the Stove cabinet. There I will tie the stove to the Romex in the J Box.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong or if you have a simpler solution. I have a racketier splice box just in case it's ok to run the Romex from the wall to the last J box without the BX armor.
Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: A diagram or pictures with dimensions would help a lot. There is nothing magic about Romex. And I suspect your BX may not actually be BX. But basically Romex (non-metallic cable) is either inside walls or in hidden places or *protected from damage*. Protection from damage can be certain types of metal or plastic conduit or pieces of metal or wood. If you use conduit then you can, instead of Romex, use individual wires rated for that use, which is easier to feed through conduit than Romex. There are also "wire whips" that are metal with wires already inside them often used for the last few ft.

Comment: What is the amps of the cooktop?  10 gauge is only good up to 30 amps, if cooktop is more, then more work/new cable required.

Comment: To start with...What size is the breaker? We've seen a few-too-many creative choices in cooktop/range/oven wiring size not to ask that question, though there are some odd rules that come into play if the same breaker is controlling a cooktop and a separate oven.

Comment: Where are you located, anyway?